# How to stay logged in to multiple websites

Tags: internet-explorer

I have multiple users that all must log into a select few websites 10 to 15 times a day.

They are all secure enough websites that remember passwords isn't an option.

I remember I once had a pal (in the same industry) who had an extension on his IE that continually pinged all the websites that he had on a list, so that he never had to re-log during the day.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?  All my users waste a significant amount of time re-logging into a batch of about 10 different sites over and over and over due to inactivity.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what industry is it that requires this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 0):

[AutoRefresher for IE](http://www.xwen.org/node/6):

> It's a small add-on for Internet Explorer that automatically reloads the current page at regular intervals.

[image: 2]